# chat in java not synchronized (sockets, threads)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, chat

I'm trying to figure out a way to get an instance of a **server** to negotiate between two **clients** by creating a chat thread between them.

I created this project, and it "almost" works... but it seems like there is a buffer of synch problem.

when writing a line in one side (i.e Client#1), it doesn't pass to the other side (i.e Client#2), but only after Client#2 trys to pass a line too.

I know there might be better ways to implement this, but I'd like to understand what's wrong with *my* code.

your help would be great!

***the code:***

**server**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int id = 1;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Server");

        try
        {
           ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4321);

            while (true)
            {
                Socket client1Socket = serverSocket.accept();
                Socket client2Socket = serverSocket.accept();

                System.out.println("clients connected from ports: \n"
                        + client1Socket.getPort() + ", " + client2Socket.getPort());

                Thread client1Thread = new ServerThread(client1Socket, client2Socket, id);
                client1Thread.start();
                id++;

                Thread client2Thread = new ServerThread(client2Socket, client1Socket, id);
                client2Thread.start();
                id++;
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**server thread**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ServerThread extends Thread 
{
    Socket sourceSocket;
    Socket destSocket;
    int id;

    public ServerThread(Socket src, Socket dst, int n) 
    {
        sourceSocket = src;
        destSocket = dst;
        id = n;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner clientInput = new Scanner(sourceSocket.getInputStream());
            PrintStream destOutput = new PrintStream(destSocket.getOutputStream());
            destOutput.println("You are chatting with Client " + id);

            boolean more = true;
            while (more) 
            {
                String input = clientInput.nextLine();
                destOutput.println(input);

                if (input.equals("Q"))
                {
                    more = false;
                }
            }
            sourceSocket.close();
            destSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**client**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Client 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Client");

        try
        {
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4321);

            System.out.println("Connection Established");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println(input.nextLine());

            boolean more = true;

            while (more) 
            {
                String text = in.nextLine();
                output.println(text);
                String nextInput = input.nextLine();

                if (nextInput == null) 
                {
                    more = false;
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println(nextInput);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the 2 sockets.  A socket is asynchronously bi-directional.  You can fork one thread for reading and one for writing using the sample single socket.

Comment: @Gray I think that two separate sockets are for two separate clients connecting and talking to each other via server.

Comment: I would try `flush()`ing output after every write

Comment: I would try `flush()` after every write exactly what @GermannArlington said. Try this and see if it works for you.

Comment: @Gray: what GermannArlington said was right. each socket is for a different user.

Comment: @GermannArlington: I actually did that before posting here, but since it didn't help, I removed it and posted as is, or maybe it's because I didn't know where to put it. can you please advise?

Comment: @3kings: can you please advise of where to put the flush call? I tried it before writing here but it didn't help.

Comment: @theexplorer You should call `flush()` after every output. So after all of the `output.println("")` and `destOutput.println("")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your client code, the line `String text = in.nextLine();` will block your thread. That means if you never type in anything in your client, you can not receive anything. So the solution is to put your message receiving code in another thread. such as:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                            System.out.println(input.nextLine());
                        }
                    }

                });
                thread.start();

                while (true) 
                {
                    String text = in.nextLine();
                    output.println(text);
//                String nextInput = input.nextLine();
                    ......................
                }
```